# Program to track customizations/versions of multiple application instances

Tags: controls, version, versioning

We are a small software company who have a unique installation of the software for each of our customers - we call it an instance.

Each instance can be a slightly different version and can have dozens of customizations. 
We have a number of staff who make changes to these instances and we would like to be able to track these changes:

1. See the version history of the application
2. See the history of each customization, including notes about any changes to files/settings
3. Track changes to our Windows environment, including dates of hotfixes and updates etc

Can anyone recommend a tool with a GUI that might assist with documenting this information?
Traditional Version Control software doesn't seem appropriate for this.